# How do I place these div's next to each other to create a 3x2 layout

Tags: html, css

How do place these div's next to each other in a 3x2 row instead of rows of 1.

Should I make the event-box and event-info as one div instead of two separate div's? I've tried to combine them as one div and given the `<p>` the event-info class but that didn't work out. I've also tried different sizes for both of the div's and the container to maybe push them next to each other, but that also didn't work. See my code below.

```css
 .event-box{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 30rem;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(/assets/images/placeholderimg4.jpg);}

    .event-info{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 30rem;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(77, 75, 75, 0.1);}

    .container{
    height: 100%;
    width: 64rem;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    padding: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="event-box">
    <h3 class="event-text">Event 1</h3>
   </div>
            <div class="event-info">
    <p>1</p>
   </div>

   <div class="event-box">
    <h3 class="event-text">Event 2</h3>
   </div>
            <div class="event-info">
    <p>2</p>
   </div>

   <div class="event-box">
    <h3 class="event-text">Event 3</h3>
   </div>
            <div class="event-info">
    <p>3</p>
   </div>

   <div class="event-box">
    <h3 class="event-text">Event 4</h3>
   </div>
            <div class="event-info">
    <p>4</p>
   </div>

   <div class="event-box">
    <h3 class="event-text">Event 5</h3>
   </div>
            <div class="event-info">
    <p>5</p>
   </div>

   <div class="event-box">
    <h3 class="event-text">Event 6</h3>
   </div>
            <div class="event-info">
    <p>6</p>
   </div>
            

  </div>
```

Comment: The HTML seems *broken* with a lot of closing `div` tags that seem out of place. You seem to be wanting a "card" layout. I suggest you look into flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a wrap div, like 'event' for it :

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class='event'>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='event'>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='event'>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info">
            <p>3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='event'>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 4</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info">
            <p>4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='event'>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 5</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info">
            <p>5</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='event'>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 6</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info">
            <p>6</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And a little css addition:

```
.event{
  display:inline-block;
  width:49%;
}
```

Try it - https://jsfiddle.net/5vz3Lhwc/

Comment: glad to hear that. You can mark this, as an answer to your question then.. :)

Answer (score 2):

So I used CSS grid for this.
I did combine your event-info and event-box div's together to make them one object in the grid.

```css
.event-box {
            height: 5rem;
            width: 30rem;
            float: left;
            clear: both;
            padding: 0;
            margin-top: 1rem;
            text-align: center;
            background: url(/assets/images/placeholderimg4.jpg);
        }
        
        .event-info {
            height: 5rem;
            width: 30rem;
            float: left;
            clear: both;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: rgba(77, 75, 75, 0.1);
        }
        
        .container {
            height: 100%;
            width: 64rem;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            padding: 0;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
            grid-template-rows: auto auto;
            grid-gap: 2rem;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 1</h3>
            <div class="event-info">
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 2</h3>
            <div class="event-info">
                <p>2</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 3</h3>
            <div class="event-info">
                <p>3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 4</h3>
            <div class="event-info">
                <p>4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 5</h3>
            <div class="event-info">
                <p>5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-box">
            <h3 class="event-text">Event 6</h3>
            <div class="event-info">
                <p>6</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So in the container class I added a display of grid (to use grid functions) and then I added grid-template-columns (which allows you to specify how many columns you want to include) and a grid-template-rows to do the same thing for the rows. I then added a grid-gap to separate the div tags a bit but this value can be played with depending on the desired gap.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It works well displaying them in columns. But for some reason the event info box got pushed inside the event-box and displaying it on top of it (maybe due some other CSS applying to it, but I don't know yet what) Because in you're snippet it's exactly what I want. I've now used Reidenshi method commented below which works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the power of Flexbox! Wrap each `row` in a div with class row and each column in a div with class `col`. Example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <div class="event-box">
        <h3 class="event-text">Event 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="event-info">
        <p>1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="event-box">
        <h3 class="event-text">Event 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="event-info">
        <p>2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="event-box">
        <h3 class="event-text">Event 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="event-info">
        <p>3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col">
      <div class="event-box">
        <h3 class="event-text">Event 4</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="event-info">
        <p>4</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="event-box">
        <h3 class="event-text">Event 5</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="event-info">
        <p>5</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="event-box">
        <h3 class="event-text">Event 6</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="event-info">
        <p>6</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the added elements:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  width: 33%;
  flex: 1;
}
```

*Edit: CSS Grid might be an even easier solution.*